# Location access timed out, position unavaiable in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have geolocation running in my app. In Xiaomi device in which i'm working on works fine. I tried on 2 other devices, and got Location request timed out error. Here's the code i have:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { View, AsyncStorage, Dimensions, PermissionsAndroid } from 'react-native';

const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window')


const ASPECT_RATIO = width / height
const LATITUDE_DELTA = 0.0922
const LONGITUDE_DELTA = LATITUDE_DELTA * ASPECT_RATIO

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      initialPosition: {
        latitude: null,
        longitude: null,
        latitudeDelta: null,
        longitudeDelta: null
      }
    }
  }

  requestLocationPermission = async () => {
    try {
      const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
        {
          'title': 'Location Permission',
          'message': 'This App needs access to your location ' +
                     'so we can know where you are.'
        }
      )
      if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
        console.log("You can use locations ")

        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
          let lat = parseFloat(position.coords.latitude)
          let long = parseFloat(position.coords.longitude)
          
          let initialRegion = {
            latitude: lat,
            longitude: long,
            latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
            longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA
          }
    
          this.setState({ initialPosition: initialRegion })
          this.setState({ markerPosition: initialRegion })
        },
          (error) => alert(JSON.stringify(error)),
          { enableHighAccuracy: false, timeout: 5000, maximumAge: 10000  }
        )
      } else {
        console.log("Location permission denied")
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.warn(err)
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.requestLocationPermission()
  }



}



export default App
```

**Some additional information:**

- React Native version: 0.57.8
- Platform: Android
- Dev tools: Android SDK v27

i have tried switching enableHighAccuracy to false but that didn't help. The error i get is like this:

[image: error image]

Comment: Goto location settings and enable High Accuracy.

Comment: Try also to increase the timeout. Which is actually set to 5000

Comment: I did set 5000 but same error @RudolfCicko

Comment: Try removing the maximumAge: 10000 option parameter. This option could cause geolocation to either timeout or crash the app.

Comment: I also removed the third parameter maximumAge but still got same error @RudolfCicko

Comment: when i enable high accuracy on location settings it work's for me. thanks @RakeshMakluri